# How to loop over a condition until the values have converged? (Newton Raphson Method)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, newtons-method

For the Newton-Raphson Method, I'm asked to write a loop to call the function until it has converged so that the values of x(n) and x(n+1) differ by less than a small number e=10^-8, however, I am not quite sure how to create this loop.

Here's my code so far

```
def newton_step(f, fp, x0):
     return x0-(f(x0)/fp(x0))

import numpy as np
def f(x):
    return x**3 + x**2 +2 

def fp(x): 
    return 3*x**2 + 2*x

x = newton_step(f, fp, (x0))
count = 0 #to count the number of iterations required to satisfy the condition
while (x0 - x) <= 10**-8:
    x0 = newton_step(f, fp, (x0))
    count += 1
    print(x0, x)
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you expirience?

Comment: I got "NameError: name 'x0' is not defined"

Comment: You're using a function to step 2 values closer to one another, right? You must provide those 2 starting values (x, x0)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your comparison operator is backwards, try:

`while (x0 - x) > 10**-8:`

so that it will loop, continuing `while` the diff is `greater than` `10^-8` (breaking out of the loop once it is less than that value)

Also, you'll want to make sure that your code sets an initial value for `x0` before the loop (so there is something to compare)

Comment: I was confused at what that x0 is, so it's just any random value or the solution of this expression?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I can see at least 2 issues with your code -

1. You don't update `x`
2. if `x0<x` then the loop will end but they can differ in more the `10^-8`
3. Wrong conditionn

To sum this up I would change the loop -

```
while abs(x0-x) >= 10**-8:
    new_x = newton_step(f, fp, (x0))
    x = x0
    x0 = new_x
    count +=1
    print(x0, x)
```

Comment: I keep getting "NameError: name 'x0' is not defined"

Comment: I assumed it was defined earlier in the code

Comment: The thing I'm struggling with is whether they're asking me for a finite value/the actual root for this equation or if they're asking to me call the function again such that x0 = (f, fp, (x0))

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop runs as long as the difference is smaller, but it should run as long as the difference is bigger. Change `while (x0 - x) <= 10**-8` to `while (x0 - x) >= 10**-8`.

Comment: Thank you so much!